# Using rounding to make floating point operations deterministic

Tags: java, floating-point

I have implemented a lockstep model using a simulation that has to be determinstic. For exact positions i use floats. Now i face the problem of them not being deterministic on every hardware / os. The simulation depends on vector maths with and scaling a few vectors each tick but also calculating exponential values.

Now I'm curious if it would be enough if I would round the floats to 4 places after the decimal point to achieve determinism, cause i only apply 5-10 operations to each float each tick.

Comment: 'For exact positions I use floats' is already a contradiction in terms.

Comment: :) By that i mean not using a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First using `double`s would already decrease approximation errors a bit further. Then rounding might be just sufficiently deterministic.

Also use [**strictfp**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp) which does just what you intend to do.

Comment: I think strictfp would be a possible solution. I put this keyword in front of a class and of a method, none of them work. I still get different results depending on the system, May this be due to me running one version on Windows and the other one on Android(which is not running a "default" JVM)?

Comment: Android translates JVM bytecode to Darvik, a non-JVM base. So that may be the case. Using BigDecimal probably is out of the question (performance).

Comment: So using strictfp it should work on all systems supported by the Oracle JVM?

Comment: It should work on all certified JVMs. There are others. As strictfp is a kind of emulation, I should expect it to be quite portable. Maybe some embedded JVMs (JavaME) do not even _have_ floating point.

Comment: Is there any easy way to force libraries like LWJGLs util library to use strictfp? If i call those methods from my own method which is marked with strictfp, will they use the exact precision as speciefied in IEEE 754? What happens if I extend the classes I need and mark them as strictfp? Will I still call the original methods without strictfp?

Comment: No, you would need to "normalize" every single result. Floating point is just an approximation to real numbers. Unsuitable for financial software, but doable for physics. You are already using double, isn't it? Intermediate rounding to N decimals could be done with a MathContext and for a moment using BigDecimal. You might be able to find a custom ClassLoader that patches the strictfp to the class, maybe using ASM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109157/discussion-between-user2912528-and-joop-eggen).